# In Powershell, is there a way to stop a service, specify a wait time, and then have that service restart?

Tags: powershell-5.0

I need to create a script that will get a service, stop it, and wait 60 seconds before restarting the service. What Cmdlets would I be incorporating?

I've tried utilizing the "Restart-Service" cmdlet, since the help description claims it is designed to start and restart a given service, but none of the associated parameters offer a way to set a specified time before restarting the service.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$serviceName="MyService";
$waitTime = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1
$service = Get-Service -Name $serviceName 
$service.Stop()
$service.WaitForStatus("Stopped", $waitTime)
$service.Start()
$service.WaitForStatus("Running", $waitTime)
```

You can query the service by display name if you would like also.
You have to check if the service is running otherwise stop will throw an exception